# Asynchronous Call to Timer

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an application that shows the system statistics but it also executes a timer each second to update the current CPU clock speed. I have tried numerous solutions but none seem to work for me. I will attach my code below. I am using the System.Management DLL to call the stats I am wanting. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace ezCPU
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = this.Text + " - v" + Application.ProductVersion;
            getCPUInfo();
        }

        public string convertClockSpeed(string s)
        {
            double clockSpeed = Convert.ToDouble(s);
            double newClockSpeed = (clockSpeed / 1000);
            return Math.Round(newClockSpeed, 2).ToString() + " GHz";
        }

        public void getCPUInfo()
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher myProcessorObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor");

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in myProcessorObject.Get())
            {
                string cpuName = obj["Name"].ToString();
                txtCPUName.Text = cpuName;

                string cpuManufacturer = obj["Manufacturer"].ToString();
                if (cpuManufacturer == "GenuineIntel")
                {
                    txtCPUManufacturer.Text = "Genuine Intel";
                }
                else
                {
                    txtCPUManufacturer.Text = cpuManufacturer;
                }

                string cpuCores = obj["NumberOfCores"].ToString();
                txtCores.Text = cpuCores;

                string cpuThreads = obj["ThreadCount"].ToString();
                txtThreads.Text = cpuThreads;

                string cpuMaxSpeed = obj["MaxClockSpeed"].ToString();
                txtClockSpeed.Text = convertClockSpeed(cpuMaxSpeed);
            }
        }  

        private void cpuTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher myProcessorObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor");

            foreach(ManagementObject obj in myProcessorObject.Get())
            {
                string currentClockSpeed = obj["CurrentClockSpeed"].ToString();
                txtCPUSpeed.Text = convertClockSpeed(currentClockSpeed);
            }  
        } 
    }
}
```

This is the result of the code. However, I am unable to move the form around while it is still updating.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/5770d7a0eabcf5f648537a7d9ebc0bff.gif]

Comment: I recommend creating a class to put getCPUInfo() and convertClockSpeed(string s) in. It will make your code better. C# methods should also start with a capital and tell exactly what is done in there, so that even non-programmers can understand it.

Comment: I am going to do that once I get everything I need to working. Refactoring is next on the agenda once I am able to get everything hooked in and working!

Comment: What are you asking us? Also, what does "I have tried numerous solutions but none seem to work for me." mean?

Comment: Use WPF avoid Forms

Comment: You may want to have a look into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/benwilli/asynchronous-infinite-loops-instead-of-timers).

Comment: @enigmativity I am wanting to update the text box displaying the current CPU speed but I want to the UI to be usable without delays.

Comment: @sebastias I checked out the documentation and it is much closer to what I am trying to accomplish! However, there is still 'lag' when changing tabs, attempting to move the form, closing the application, etc. Here is my updated code: https://pastebin.com/ptPbeu1k

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the windows forms timer? It has the elapsed event that even spins up a background thread to do the work, keeping your ui responsive:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer aTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

        // Create a timer and set a two second interval.
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;

        // Hook up the tick event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Tick += OnTimedEvent;

        // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;

        // Start the timer
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // update your statistics here
    }
}
```

If you want to update the ui there, then the tick event is the way to go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for such a timely response. However, I am receiving errors on the code listed above. The error states: "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Timers.Timer to System.Windows.Forms.Timer" on the line declaring aTimer.

https://i.gyazo.com/c66b7d4c22bc032d780ec4e202ecf72d.png

Comment: So, I changed the initialization code above the constructor to this:
"public System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();"

This removed the errors but then I received the following error:
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtCPUSpeed' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'"

Comment: I am sorry if this seems novel but I have recently just worked in ASP .NET MVC so trying to create a C# software application seems alien versus how it did previously. You can find the most up to date code here: https://pastebin.com/rG46wG9X

Comment: Check the updated code.  My mistake for leaving the second initialization. Keep the forms timer declaration and let me know if it works.

Comment: You should also use the tick event to update ui, not the background threads.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for your assistance. I was hesitant to post on SO because of the reputation people receive when trying to get clarification on something. Secondly, I have posted the new code below which outlines the errors I now receive.

https://pastebin.com/8sHie9zT

Lastly, I am unsure what you mean by using the tick event to update the UI. I get what you are saying but am unsure why that is the case when it was previously stated that you update the stats on the OnTimedEvent method/event handler. Thanks again!

Comment: The errors are on .Tick and .AutoReset if that makes it easier to find.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to change the signature to `private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)` so that it can be assigned to tick. Sorry to hear about such a reputation but even if it's sometimes true, most people do their best to help and feel happy to do it without being judgemental!

Comment: @ChrisHarris - What do you mean by "I was hesitant to post on SO because of the reputation people receive when trying to get clarification on something."?

Comment: @ChrisHarris - I think a lot of the time people feel there's rudeness, but the community here tries to ensure a high level of quality of both questions and answers. Many new people just feel that they're being picked on because the feedback is very picky to make sure the quality meets the bar.

Comment: @Enigmativity I can see that as well! I tried my best to clarify what I am trying to accomplish. While the responses have been helpful and helped me learn new techniques, I am still unable to achieve what I want. The infinite loops was the closest I have came but the UI is still unresponsive for a short time because of the delay.

Comment: @ChrisHarris - Did you try the above code with `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

Comment: @enigmativity I did and the UI still is unresponsive while the work is being done. I can move it after the work is complete but then it will be unresponsive once again.